# Update django from 1 to 3 in a docker container: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'secret_key' when building the image

Tags: django, docker, secret-key

I have inherited a project in Django 1 and I am trying to convert to Django 3.1.3. To complicate things a bit I am running it in a docker container

I have the following code in my app.settings.py:

```
def generate_secret_key(file_name):
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)"
    key = get_random_string(50, chars)
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        f.write('SECRET_KEY = "%s"' % key)


try:
    from secret_key import *
except ImportError:
    SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    generate_secret_key(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, "secret_key.py"))
    from secret_key import *
```

when I try building the image the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mcvitty/mcvitty/settings.py", line 234, in <module>
    from secret_key import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'secret_key'
```

Line 234 is

```
from secret_key import *
```

The code was working in Django 1. If no secret key module is found, the function generate_secret_key should run generating the module secret_key.py and the program should procede smoothly but i get an error instead. What is different in Django 3.1.3?

This is my project structure:

```
mcvitty
 |
 | manage.py
 | mcvitty
    |
    | settings.py
```

Comment: you have `from secret_key import *` in the `except`  block....

Comment: Hi @ivissani the error is the line 234 after the try: statement. Not the from *secret_key import * in the except block that is called after a key get generated

Answer (score 0):

`secret_key` should be a path relative to the main Django project or the path relative to your current file. Technically, it should be :

`from App_name.file_name import *`.

It would be better if you share your project structure.